# wix-fetch vs wix-http-functions

Tags: function, velo

I need to work with data from a SQL Server DB, exposed in a REST API. I don't understand what are the differences if I use wix-fetch or wix-http-functions. It seems that with any of them I could do the same operations. Which is the best option?
Arturo

Answer (score 0):

Actually, wix-fetch and wix-http-functions are quite different, and in some ways opposites.

- wix-fetch: Used to consume an API that someone else has exposed.
- wix-http-functions: Used to expose your own API for someone else to consume.

(You probably want to use wix-fetch to work with data from an SQL Server that exposes a REST API.)

Comment: Sam, understood. Thank you!