# How to make APIs for a mobile app from Wix website already made?

Tags: velo

What is required from me is making API requests from an already made website using Wix I don't know if Wix has this feature same as easily making the website don't know where to look or where to start any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

If you are looking to make an API call **from a mobile app** to a Wix Website then you need to use Corvid's HTTP functions (https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-http-functions.html)

If you are looking to make an API call **from a Wix site** then you need to use Fetch (https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-fetch.html)

Read the difference between http-functions and wix-fetch here: [wix-fetch vs wix-http-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326425/wix-fetch-vs-wix-http-functions?rq=1)

Comment: I have a database which is a list of categories I can't make a get request